# Provisioning profile status is Pending

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

After creating Profile the status is still PENDING. How long it takes?

Its spend about 2 hour but status is still pending.

[image]

I am getting this problem first time.

Comment: I have been trying to add new device in existing provisioning profile and its showing pending from last 2 days. Looks like devforums.apple.com is also down.

Comment: I'm currently getting it as well, only been waiting for about 10 minutes so far but it is still pending.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about third party services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue but now it works. I tried out many things but nothing helped and I haven't seen any message about a maintenance by apple.

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting this too, It appears to be an issue with Apple. Mine has been pending for 30 minutes.
EDIT: It's fixed

Answer (score 3):

Apple were apparently performing maintenance for over 24 hours yesterday. There was a message:

> "We are performing maintenance on the provisioning service"

Now they have removed this message and the provisioning service is still not working. It used to be immediate and as soon as your sent a request it would be done a few seconds later after your refresh the page.

I'm outraged as I actually signed up to the program again yesterday to start building an app. The iPhone simulator doesn't work for video editing for some reason and I can't deploy to to the iPhone without provisioning so I have no way to test my code.

The lack of information from Apple is ridiculous seeing as they are well aware there is a problem but have not even bothered to notify the users and have even taken down the old notice. This must be very confusing for any novice developers who are provisioning for the first time and is also severely delaying the development of my app.

Comment: I have the same issue now! I have just renewed my developer program (some 10 days BEFORE expiring), and now I have this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes for me also this happened. See apple message in same page.

```
"We are performing maintenance on the provisioning service"
```

Also someone reported same issue in [apple forums here.](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/180298?tstart=0)

Comment: there is not any apple message.. but now issue is solved automatically no need to send mail to apple..